# Trying to send random number with post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm trying to send a post request with a random generated number.
My script generates the random number fine.
My problem is that it's not sending the generated number correctly. It only sends the first part. Which is `100` and not the generated number.

You can see where I've added the variable(number) to the request shown below in the code.

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
var number = [[100,Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)]]

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 84) {
console.log('started');
$.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
                l: parseInt(number), //<<<< MY ERROR IS HERE!!
                w: ("15"),
                c: ("#0000ff"),
                o: ("100"),
                f: ("1"),
                _: ("false")
            })
console.log(number)
}
};
```

I've put `MY ERROR IS HERE!!` where the error may be happening at.
So right now it's sending that post request data of l: as `[[100]]` I would like it to send with the generated number. Making the l: data like `[[100,75]]` (As a example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `parseInt`, you can use `JSON.stringify` to get your array as string:

```
l: JSON.stringify(number), // => "[[100,75]]"
```

Edit: Define `number` inside the function:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var number = [[100,Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)]];
  ...
```

Comment: Its only generates the random number once. Than I have to refresh just to make it regenerate a new number. How to make it generate a random number everytime the key is pressed.

Comment: Define `number` inside the function (see edited answer).